# One liner in bash that copies files with a number appended to the filename

Tags: bash, fortran

I'm trying to include a command in my Fortran 90 code that copies a certain file to a backup location. If I simply copy the file, the code would be

```
cp -f myfile.nml output/codebkp/myfile.nml
```

But I was looking for something that could identify if there were previous files. For example, if the file didn't exist before, if would copy it to `myfile.nml.00`. If the directory already had a `myfile.nml.02` it would copy it to `myfile.nml.03` and so on.

It kind of has to be a one liner because I'm putting it into my Fortran code, so I'm forced (I think) to use the `CALL SYSTEM()` statement.

The best attempt I can make is something like

```
cp myfile.nml output/codebkp/myfile.nml.$((`ls output/codebkp/myfile.nml.* | awk '{print $NF}' | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'`+1))
```

But that gives me an error when there's no file (although surprisingly it still kind of works even with the error), and doesn't work anymore after two files, giving me this error

```
bash: 1
2+1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2+1")
```

Any ideas?

By the way, I'm doing it this way on Fortran because I know of no better way to do it from there. But if there's a better way to do it other than with `CALL SYSTEM()` please let me know!

Comment: Can't you (in Fortran) simply have a loop with inquire-by-filename, or does it have a to be bash?

Comment: You could write a multiline bash (or Python or whatever) script and save it to a file, and then call that file using your one-liner command from fortran.

Comment: @francescalus I really don't know fortran very well. I guess I could, but I just don't know how to. I have virtually zero experience with fortran

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? Can't you just separate the commands by a semicolon? Also, how would you know the file's location? Any way, you can add the current `date` to the end of the file name to make it unique.

Comment: @dramzy you're right, I can I guess. I would just prefer a one-liner for readability and space reasons

Comment: Are you compiling with gfortran? Look up `execute_command_line`, which is part of the Fortran 2008 standard and should considered in new code for future portability. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html#EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my bash (GNU bash, version 4.4.5) the first time the command worked ok.

```
$ls
>Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  myfile.nml.02  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
$cp myfile.nml.02 myfile.nml.$((`ls myfile.nml.* |awk '{print $NF}' |awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'` + 1))
$ls
>Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  myfile.nml.02  myfile.nml.3  Pictures  Public  Templates Videos
```

But the second time didn't work. LS yelds all nml files, middle awk is not isolating the last file as you might wish.

```
$ls myfile.nml.* |awk '{print $NF}' |awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'
>02
>3
```

If you replace middle awk with tail -1 should work.

```
$ls myfile.nml.* |tail -1 |awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'
>3
$cp myfile.nml.3 myfile.nml.$((`ls myfile.nml.* |tail -1 |awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'` + 1))
$ls myfile.nml.* 
>myfile.nml.02  myfile.nml.3  myfile.nml.4
```

PS: Mind the missing zero ....

Comment: Yeah, I actually independently arrived at this version, which includes the zero: ``"max=`ls output/codebkp/param.nml.* | tail -1 | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'`; max=${max#0}; &
!&cp param.nml output/codebkp/param.nml.`printf '%02d' $((max+1))`"``